# Mac Air Flash Drive Retrieval

Tags: macbook-pro, data-recovery

If my Mac Air has been water damaged, can I still retrieve the data from the flash drives even though the machine will not start at all?

Answer (score 2):

If the SSD is undamaged, yes. You could still open the Macbook Air, get the SSD and place it, either in other MacBook Air or [those Enclosure things](http://www.google.com/search?num=100&hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&biw=1128&bih=685&q=SSD%20Enclosure&oq=SSD%20Enclosure&aq=f&aqi=g1g-c6g1g-c2&aql=&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i7l6j0j0i7l2.814.1487.0.1843.4.4.0.0.0.0.89.345.4.4.0...0.0.ImBeYdcbVtg).

[iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Air) has a step-by-step guide for replacing the SSD.